# Datagrip comment header hotkey

Tags: datagrip

At my company I'd like to create a standard for the creation of database functions with a comment header, something like:

```
/*
==================================================
Author:     John Doe
Created At: (Automatically fills in current date)
Where used: User fills in URL or whatever
==================================================
*/
```

Is there a way in data grip to bind this text to a hotkey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course: snippet functionality is called Live Templates.

1. Open *Settings*
2. Go to *Live Templates*
3. Create a new template with an abbreviation, say, 'com'.
4. In editor type 'com' and press *Tab*.

[image]

PS. Play with the variables for the placeholders.

Comment: Awesome thanks, will this be in the latest update of datagrip?